# Change devServer options for Storybook manager configuration

Tags: webpack, storybook

I wanted to change the `devServer` property for `managerWebpack` in Storybook configuration, but seems it's not working.

I trying to add `launch-editor-middleware` to devServer. But even other options not working, like `open` that by default opens the browser, I can't override them. I see only manager config in the console.

Here is part of my config in main.js:

```js
const openInEditor = require('launch-editor-middleware');

module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-webpack5',
  },
  // .....
  managerWebpack: async (config, options) => {
    console.log(config);

    config.devServer = {
      open: false,
      onBeforeSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
        console.log(devServer);
        devServer.app.use('/__open-in-editor', openInEditor());
      },
    };

    return config;
  }
  // .....
}
```